# Cw complex $\Sigma_g$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces, cw-complexes

Consider the oriented connected compact surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$ with its standard CW structure. How do I write down the attaching map for the single $2$-cell and how can it be proven that it is continuous? I am interested in a formal (algebra standards) proof not a dirty topologists proof (write down a picture and claim map, which is not even defined formally, is continuous).

Comment: You should try to define it piecewise, on $4g$ arcs of the length $\pi/(2g)$ on $S^1$, each of which is mapped to an edge by a map which only identifies the end points of that arc.

Comment: easier said than done :) and how to prove that it is continuous? I know the topologists will hate me for this question

Comment: Well the map on the first arc $\{e^{2pi it}\mid t\in[0,1/4g]\}$ is $e^{2\pi i t}\mapsto e^{8g\pi it}$, where the image is in the $S^1$-circle corresponding to first edge. On the subsequent arcs you have to precompose with some translation. Note that the characteristic map of each cell is a quotient map, so the image of the edge is indeed an $S^1$.

Comment: You might have missed a good rigorous course in topology, like the topologists went through. Try Munkres book "Topology".

Comment: @LeeMosher: I know Munkres' book, and I don't consider topology in general to be nonrigorous, general topology is basically set theory and algebraic topology mostly algebra. I am just saying that none of the standard books carries out some nontrivial example formally and explicitly. they just write down a picture and describe it with some handwaving, pointing out something that is intuitevely obvious, but frustrating on the formal level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StefanHamcke indicates in his comment, what topologists learn to do in their training is to take their knowledge of CW complexes as learned from books like Hatcher's or Spanier's, and to instantly translate intuitive descriptions of CW complexes into rigorous descriptions. This process is mechanical and uninteresting once you learn how to do it. However, until you have reached the mechanical and uninteresting stage, you should study how to carry out this process.

Here is what you get if you carry out out this translation process starting with the standard picture of pairing up the sides of an octagon to form $\Sigma_2$ by using the pairing formula $AB\bar A \bar B C D \bar C \bar D$.

Start with the $0$-skeleton $\Sigma^0_2$: a single point $p$.

Define the $1$-skeleton $\Sigma^1_2$ by attaching four edges to $p$. More specifically, starting with a disjoint union $X = \{p\} \cup \alpha \cup \beta \cup \gamma \cup \delta$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are each homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, form the quotient space $\Sigma^1_2$ of $X$ by attaching each of the points of $\partial \alpha, \partial \beta, \partial \gamma, \partial\delta$ to the point $p$. Let $\pi : X \to \Sigma^1_2$ be the quotient map. (Here I assume that one knows how to translate the "attaching" language into a specific description of the partition which defines the quotient map: the "attaching" language describes a relation on a set, and one takes the equivalence relation generated by that relation).

Define four paths $A,B,C,D :[0,1] \to \Sigma^1_2$: take the homeomorphisms from $[0,1]$ to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ resp.; compose with the inclusion maps into $X$; and compose with the quotient map $\pi : X \to \Sigma^1_2$. Each of these four paths is a composition of continuous maps therefore continuous. Each of these paths has both of its endpoints at $p$.

Define a path $f : [0,1] \to \Sigma^1_2$ by converting the pairing formula $AB\bar A \bar B C D \bar C \bar D$ into a concatenation formula and picking a way to associate, for example
$$f = A* (B* (\bar A* (\bar B* (C* (D* (\bar C* \bar D))))))
$$
(Here I assume one knows the formula for concatenation of two paths and for the reverse of a path, and the lemma regarding the continuity of these operations. Also, feel free to associate in any other fashion.)

Define $\Sigma_2$ to be the quotient space of the disjoint union $\Sigma^1_2 \cup D^2$ by identifying $e^{2 \pi i t} \in \partial D^2$ with $f(t) \in \Sigma^1_2$.

Comment: I thought I am supposed to learn how to do this from Hatcher, but he just gives some intuition, and, as many people object, he is often very sloppy. It would be very interesting to know what Serre would say about hatchers book

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller: Hatcher's book assumes that the reader has mastered constructions of this sort from a book like Munkres. And you might be interested to look up some of Serre's work on topology, such as his book "Trees".

Comment: most constructions (adjunction spaces etc) are not even treated in Munkres, so I don't think so. Also since Hatcher isn't ashamed of giving full details of trivial algebra proofs (often in the most unelegant way). as for Serre I know he did lots of famous contributions to algebraic, e.g. homotopy theory. If someone like him critizes topology books for their use of pictures, I guess I should believe him

Comment: You may find that "Trees" surprises you, if you are open to surprise.